# How to filter objects that contains object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

could you help with these problem.

I need to filter the items in the array that contains certains activities in their object array. Heres is the code:

```
let userArray = [{
    name: "alonso",
    age:16,
    hobbies: [{activity:"videogames", id: 1}, {activity:"watch tv", id:2}]
  },
  {
    name: "aaron",
    age:19,
    hobbies: [{activity:"videogames", id:1}, {activity:"soccer", id:8}]
  },
  {
    name: "Luis",
    age:27,
    hobbies: [{activity:"code", id:3}, {activity:"soccer", id:8}]
}]
```

if `"videogames"` is passed by string the output expected is:

```
[{
   name: "alonso",
   age:16,
   hobbies: [{activity:"videogames", id: 1}, {activity:"watch tv", id:2}]
 },
 {
   name: "aaron",
   age:19,
   hobbies: [{activity:"videogames", id:1}, {activity:"soccer", id:8}]
}]
```

Comment: Use the `Array.some()` method in the filter callback function.

Comment: The norm on the site is for questions to show what's been tried.  Consider that your filter should contain a find, like `people.filter(person => person.hobbies.find(hobby => hobby.activity === someActivity))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const userArray = [{name: 'alonso',age: 16,hobbies: [{ activity: 'videogames', id: 1 },{ activity: 'watch tv', id: 2 },],},{name: 'aaron',age: 19,hobbies: [{ activity: 'videogames', id: 1 },{ activity: 'soccer', id: 8 },],},{name: 'Luis',age: 27,hobbies: [{ activity: 'code', id: 3 },{ activity: 'soccer', id: 8 },],},]

const getUsersByActivity = (array, activity) =>  array.filter(
  user => user.hobbies.some(hobby => activity === hobby.activity)
)

const result = getUsersByActivity(userArray, 'videogames')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var users = [
{
    name: "aaron",
    age: 19,
    hobbies: [
      { activity: "videogames", id: 1 },
      { activity: "soccer", id: 8 },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Luis",
    age: 27,
    hobbies: [
      { activity: "code", id: 3 },
      { activity: "soccer", id: 8 },
    ],
  },
];

function getUsersBasedOnActivity(activity) {
  return users.filter((data) => {
    const hobbies = data.hobbies.map((hobby) => hobby.activity);
    return hobbies.includes(activity);
  });
}

console.log(getUsersBasedOnActivity('videogames'))
```

Answer (score 0):

using [array.filter](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/filter) you could filter out the objects that dont have the trait you are looking for `userArray.filter(x => x.hobbies[0].activity === "videogames");`

Answer (score 0):

```
userArray.filter(user => {
  if(user.hobbies.some(hobby => hobby.activity == "videogames")){
  return user
  }
  })
```